# xacro: substitution args not supported: No module named 'rospkg'

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am an absolute beginner to Ubuntu and ROS and to such q/a forums, so please be forgiving.
I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3  and running ROS Melodic.
I am following an old Udacity course archive.
It is about a package called simple_arm which I cloned from (https://github.com/udacity/simple_arm_01.git )

I have created my catkin workspace, initialized it, cloned from github, ran catkin_make, sourced bash.setup as according to instructions. However I get an error when run the launch command:

```
roslaunch simple_arm robot_spawn.launch
```

The error i receive is:

```
... logging to /home/karthik/.ros/log/5ae6a64a-c58b-11e9-8b56-34e6ad8bdd6e/roslaunch-UnitedForever-17751.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option.
substitution args not supported:  No module named 'rospkg'
when processing file: /home/karthik/catkin_ws/src/simple_arm/urdf/simple_arm.urdf.xacro
RLException: while processing /home/karthik/catkin_ws/src/simple_arm/launch/robot_description.xml:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/melodic/lib/xacro/xacro --inorder '/home/karthik/catkin_ws/src/simple_arm/urdf/simple_arm.urdf.xacro'] returned with code [2]. 

Param xml is <param command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder &apos;$(find simple_arm)/urdf/simple_arm.urdf.xacro'" name="robot_description"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331455/xacro:-substitution-args-not-supported:--no-module-named-%27rospkg%27/) by [karburettor](https://answers.ros.org/users/45076/karburettor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2019-08-23

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ffusco](https://answers.ros.org/users/36264/ffusco/) on 2019-08-23**:
Did you change anything from the code? I just cloned the repo and it works for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had installed Anaconda. It had changed some python path. Uninstalling it and running above code solved the error.
Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [karburettor](https://answers.ros.org/users/45076/karburettor/) with karma: 96 on 2019-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rahul K R](https://answers.ros.org/users/51502/rahul-k-r/) on 2020-02-05**:
I faced the same error. Fixed it by uninstalling anaconda3
Thanks!

**Comment by [sia](https://answers.ros.org/users/53185/sia/) on 2020-04-03**:
I faced the same error however instead of uninstalling Anaconda I install rospkg with Anaconda by running  conda install -c conda-forge rospkg (got this from https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/rospkg).
This way you don't have to uninstall Anaconda

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2020-06-02**:
I am using virtualenvironment instead of anaconda. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this error?

**Comment by [PavanMV](https://answers.ros.org/users/77083/pavanmv/) on 2021-07-03**:
you can deactivate your conda/venv environment. Now its looks for system-level python instead of your environment.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was getting the same error. The issue was that I was in a virtual environment. If your in one that's likely the issue - just run `deactivate` / `conda deactivate`

---

Originally posted by [jstm](https://answers.ros.org/users/35977/jstm/) with karma: 21 on 2022-12-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1